# jQuery improve performance of function

Tags: jquery, performance, navigation, scroll, viewport

I wrote a custom script, which checks the current viewport position and then accordingly highlights the current item in the fixed header navigation.

The order of the navigation items is the same as the order of the offset variables declaration.

I call this function on `scroll()`, but I got the feeling this not the best performance wise, since it checks all the time when a user scrolls. Maybe a better approach would be for example to check  at the end of the scroll event? But I couldn't find a way to implement that.

Do you have any idea how I could improve the performance of the functionality?

Here is my code:

```
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
            activeState();
        }
    );

function activeState() {
        var offsetHome = $('#Home').position().top;
        var offsetLeistungen = $('#Leistungen').position().top;
        var offsetPortfolio = $('#Portfolio').position().top;
        var offsetUeber = $('#Ueber').position().top;
        var offsetKontakt = $('#Kontakt').position().top;
        var headerHeight = $('.header').height();
        $('#PrimNav li').removeClass('active');
        if($window.scrollTop() <= offsetLeistungen - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        } else  if($window.scrollTop() <= offsetPortfolio - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
        } else  if($window.scrollTop() <= offsetUeber - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
        } else  if($window.scrollTop() <= offsetKontakt - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(4)').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(5)').addClass('active');
        }
    };
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements' position is fixed, then  you can move the declaration out of your activateState() function, because every time the scroll event fires it declares those variables again which is not really efficient.
You also don't have to get $(window).scrollTop() value in every if statement. Calculate it once on the scroll event and pass its value to activateState();

**Updated:**

```
var offsetHome = 0;
var offsetLeistungen = 0;
var offsetPortfolio = 0;
var offsetUeber = 0;
var offsetKontakt = 0;
var headerHeight = 0;
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
            activeState($window.scrollTop());
        }
    );

function activeState(scrollTop) {
       offsetHome = $('#Home').position().top;
       offsetLeistungen = $('#Leistungen').position().top;
       offsetPortfolio = $('#Portfolio').position().top;
       offsetUeber = $('#Ueber').position().top;
       offsetKontakt = $('#Kontakt').position().top;
       headerHeight = $('.header').height();
        $('#PrimNav li').removeClass('active');
        if(scrollTop <= offsetLeistungen - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        } else  if(scrollTop <= offsetPortfolio - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
        } else  if(scrollTop <= offsetUeber - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
        } else  if(scrollTop <= offsetKontakt - headerHeight) {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(4)').addClass('active');
        } else {
            $('#PrimNav li:nth-child(5)').addClass('active');
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately you misunderstood me, the elements position is not fixed, just the position of the header navigation where I highlight the current view-able element is fixed. The position of #Home, #Leistungen,.. is somewhere on the page and can change while the user navigates the page. But I used your `$window.scrollTop()` within the `activeState()` function call.

Comment: In this case you can still split the declaration and assignment. See the updated code above.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense! I will wait until tomorrow and see if someone else will give me their opinion and the I will decide which answer to accept. But right now you are in the lead.. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Btw: I compared the old and new function's performance, there was an average improve of 22%! :)